# Best way to store incomplete data in a relational model?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, orm

I am writing a web app that takes user input from a series of forms (think "wizard") and stores it in a SQL database as the user progresses.

Let's say they are submitting an *application form* on behalf of a *company* that has an *address*. The application form will also have a list of *supporting info*.

So the simplified schema will have 4 tables (note that each table will have plenty of other fields to capture):

```
**ApplicationForm**
Id: PK
CompanyId: FK

**Company**
Id: PK
Address: FK

**Address**
Id: PK

**SupportingInfo**
Id: PK
ApplicationFormId: FK
```

A user first starts an application form, fills in some important details over a couple of screens, then adds the company details, then adds the company address, and finally adds the list of supporting info.

Given that I cannot create the entire data model in one insert, how do I go about saving the users' input as they progress through the web pages?

When I save the ApplicationForm, I will have a FK violation because there is no Company. When I create the Company, I will have a FK violation because the Address only gets saved later. (Supporting Info does not have this problem because it has a many-to-one relation and the FK will always be valid.)

I have thought of the following:

- Do I disable constraint checks?
- Or allow the FKs to be null?
- Or create "dummy" entries in the related tables until the user enters their details?
- Or create separate data models data entry and persistance)?
- Or save "in progress" data as JSON or XML?

All the options have significant drawbacks, and the last two in particular seem like overkill for a simple user entry app.

I am working with Entity Framework and SQL Server if that makes any difference to the answers. (I realise that NoSQL may be a suggestion here, but I can't change the database.)

Comment: Couple o' things - 1. What if an application from a company that already exists is being entered, will you allow choosing an existing company? If you are just going to create a new company again, your model is flawed and there is no need for a foreign key. Same for addresses. 2. You can use surrogate or proxy tables that only have an auto-increment primary key that you then use as primary key in Company and Address tables. These surrogate tables can be inserted using ```insert CompanyProxy default values``` and get the ```scope_identity()``` inside the transaction, use that as foreign key.

Comment: The data that each user enters would be unlikely to be shared. But is sharing data a necessary condition to use a foreign key? I thought they also expressed the nature of the relationship between tables. I am using Entity Framework Code First, so may not be able to get this idea to work. I appreciate the suggestion and will have a look into how it may apply tomorrow.

Comment: You could possibly make your FK columns nullable. A more general solution is to move the relationship to a separate table, e.g. `CompanyAddress (CompanyId, AddressId)` where the association can be recorded after you've created the address.